# How to fix Angular 2 error (maybe in WebPack) while running with Cordova?

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, webpack

Environment:

```
> node -v
v6.11.0
> npm -v
3.10.10
> ng -v
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
os: win32 x64
> cordova -v
7.0.1
```

How to reproduce:

```
> ng new App
> cd App
> cordova create cordova com.mycompany.app App
> ng build --output-path=cordova/www/ --base-href .
> cd cordova
> cordova platform add android
> cordova run android
```

On device/emulator (first in my case) app is opening and showing white screen. In `chrome://inspect/#devices` I see "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined in vendor.bundle.js:5706`":

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined in vendor.bundle.js:5706](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ESEP.png)

Answer (score 0):

In `src/polyfills.ts` uncomment string `import 'core-js/es6/object';`.